# User retrieved from firebase wont setup in the activity variable

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm retrieving an User from FirebaseDatabase, in MainActivity :

```
private void initializeCurrentUser(){
        DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("users")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot != null){
                    User u = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    Log.v("DSREF", "reached");
                    setCurrentUser(u);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

checking with Logs, after :

```
User u = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
```

the user exists and it s intialized, like calling u.getEmail() returns the email of currentUser.

but, when calling

```
setCurrentUser(u);
```

which is a method from MainActivity :

```
public void setCurrentUser(User user){
        this.currentUser = user;
    }
```

the currentUser will be set with NULL value, causing NullPointerException when calling methods like currentUser.getEmail();

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when/where are you calling currentUser.getEmail();?

Comment: After setting currentUser for example

Comment: can you post the code where you get the nullpointer?

Comment: When calling ((MainActivity)getActivity)getCurrentUser().getEmail/Name/etc from a fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting the nullpointer because you call it before it is initialized with the Firebase Listener. This should fix your problem.

```
/*
 * Inside your Activity
 */
private Fragment fragment; // Store your fragment when you create it.

private void initializeCurrentUser(){
    /* .. */
    dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot != null){
                User u = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                Log.v("DSREF", "reached");
                setCurrentUser(u);
                ((MyFragment) fragment)).notifyLoaded();
            }
        }
        /* .. */
    });
}

/*
 * Inside your Fragment
 */
String email;

public void notifyLoaded() {
    // Do not call ((MainActivity)getActivity).getCurrentUser().getEmail() anywhere else in onCreate(View) etc..
    email = ((MainActivity)getActivity).getCurrentUser().getEmail();
    // Do things with non-null email now.
}
```

While this will  work, I suggest you update your Activity-Fragment communication to use Interfaces or EventBus.

Comment: the problem is that after setting the currentUser in mainActivity after downloading it from firebase instantly becomes NULL, but the User object in onDataChange is not null.

Comment: Can you add a `Log.d("TAG","setCurrentUser");` inside setCurrentUser(), and a `Log.d("TAG","onDataChange");` inside onDataChange() and then post the logs?

Comment: I have added a log in onDataChange, like the one with reached, but trying to get the email from current users, giving me the correct data.
Log.v("DSREF", u.getEmail());

Comment: then, i added a log in setCurrentUser, Log.v("DSREF", user.getEmail()); which gives me that error : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.minimalart.studentlife.models.User.getEmail()' on a null object reference

the object before passing is not null, but right after passing it becomes null

Comment: ok, in my code in setCurrentUser was:
Log.v("DSREF", currentUser.getEmail());
this.currentUser=user;

i have called getEmail before initializing that

i put two logs, before setting and after and the currentUser receive the good data

Comment: but, when calling getCurrentUser from a fragment i got NULL POINTER EXCEPTION. 

public User getCurrentUser() {
        return currentUser;
    }

Comment: Nevermind, I think your problem is that you call getCurrentUser from fragment before onDataChange is called.

Comment: no...the order is that in Main Activity:
initializing user
setting user
opening Home Fragment which calls getCurrentUser required for name, email etc

Comment: You can send email to linxydev@gmail.com and ill help you solve this, dont want to spam so comments

Answer (score 0):

Check if deserialization succeeded from database to your class User i.e. that you have all the correct fields, public default constructor and getters.

[From Firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write)

Comment: Well, either that node in database is empty, or it is an issue with the time when the method onDataChange is called and you fetch a User because it is asynchronous ( it's more likely to be that).

Comment: I did the same to retrieve a list of data from another node from database and it s fully working.

Comment: The node isnt empty